# JNI & C - Pointer to pointer

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a question related to pointers to pointers in JNI.

If I have the following function in C:

```
void myfunction(int **pp);
```

How do I get the reference of `int **pp` in Java?  And how do I pass to a JNI function the reference in order to modify it?

Can you lead me to a solution? I can work with simple pointers but not with pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 4):

*The JNI equivalent would instead substitute the method’s first argument with a long primitive array.*

```
int alloc_opaque_type(T** pp);
```

vs

```
public static native int alloc_opaque_type(long[] pp);
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work from a JNI function to a Java file, but I can't get it to work from the reference I have now in the Java file to a JNI function in order to modify it.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev That's unfortunate. I removed the link.

Comment: Oh well. Your answer was still helpful. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you cannot get a Java object as a pointer to modify it, if that's what you are asking. Nor can you convert a Java object directly into a C struct or a C++ object. You can however get a Java object as a `jobject`, manually get its primitive values (such as ints or chars from Strings) and use those values to construct whatever you need in the C code. You can cast `jint` to `int`, `jdouble` to `double`, etc..., but not `jobject` to `struct` or an array.

If you obtained a pointer and passed it into Java (as an `int`), then you can pass that `int` back to C (via JNI) and convert that `int` back to a pointer.